# Creating react element with custom attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, first app. I am trying to create a custom element with attributes of data. For the time being I am writing in plain ES5 so no JSX, Babel or ES6 yet. That will be next.

```
var myEl = React.createClass({
    displayName : 'elCont',
    render: function() {
        return(
            React.createElement('My-Shiney-Element', {
                data: data,
                conf: conf
            })
         );
     )}


var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var conf = {"show": true};
```

I can see in the html `<my-shiney-element><\my-shiney-element>` But not the attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<my-shiney-element foo="bla"><\my-shiney-element>
```

in you code you can access "foo" with "this.props.foo"

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html